# How to pass the values from one activity to previous activity

Tags: android, android-activity

How do I pass a value from one screen to its previous screen?

Consider this case: I have two activities. The first screen has one `TextView` and a button and the second activity has one `EditText` and a button.

If I click the first button then it has to move to second activity and here user has to type something in the text box. If he presses the button from the second screen then the values from the text box should move to the first activity and that should be displayed in the first activity `TextView`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending data back to the Main Activity in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920306/sending-data-back-to-the-main-activity-in-android)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass data between Activities in Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application)

Answer (score 247, accepted):

To capture actions performed on one Activity within another requires three steps.

Launch the secondary Activity (your 'Edit Text' Activity) as a subactivity by using `startActivityForResult` from your main Activity.

```
Intent i = new Intent(this,TextEntryActivity.class);    
startActivityForResult(i, STATIC_INTEGER_VALUE);
```

Within the subactivity, rather than just closing the Activity when a user clicks the button, you need to create a new Intent and include the entered text value in its extras bundle. To pass it back to the parent call `setResult` before calling `finish` to close the secondary Activity.

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
resultIntent.putExtra(PUBLIC_STATIC_STRING_IDENTIFIER, enteredTextValue);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
finish();
```

The final step is in the calling Activity: Override `onActivityResult` to listen for callbacks from the text entry Activity. Get the extra from the returned Intent to get the text value you should be displaying.

```
@Override 
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {     
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); 
  switch(requestCode) { 
    case (STATIC_INTEGER_VALUE) : { 
      if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) { 
      String newText = data.getStringExtra(PUBLIC_STATIC_STRING_IDENTIFIER);
      // TODO Update your TextView.
      } 
      break; 
    } 
  } 
}
```

Comment: This all worked for me except `new Intent(null);` was "too ambiguous" and I had to change it to `new Intent();`.

Comment: It's also worth noting that this will only work within the same context. If you start the activity from a fragment for example, it won't work because the requestCode will be different each time. You'll need to use getActivity().startActivityForResult() in the fragment.

Comment: Reto - would you mind looking at my most recent question regarding a similar circumstance.

Answer (score 10):

There are couple of ways by which you can  access variables or object in other classes or Activity.

A. Database

B. shared preferences.

C. Object serialization.

D. A class which can hold common data can be named as Common Utilities it depends on you.

E. Passing data through Intents and Parcelable Interface.

It depend upon your project needs.

A. **Database**

SQLite is an Open Source Database which is embedded into Android. SQLite supports standard relational database features like SQL syntax, transactions and prepared statements.

Tutorials -- http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

B. **Shared Preferences**

Suppose you want to store username. So there will be now two thing a **Key** Username, **Value** Value.

**How to store**

```
 // Create object of SharedPreferences.
 SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
 //now get Editor
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
 //put your value
 editor.putString("userName", "stackoverlow");

 //commits your edits
 editor.commit();
```

*Using putString(),putBoolean(),putInt(),putFloat(),putLong() you can save your desired dtatype.*

**How to fetch**

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String userName = sharedPref.getString("userName", "Not Available");
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

C. **Object Serialization**

Object serlization is used if we want to save an object state to send it over network or you can use it for your purpose also.

Use java beans and store in it as one of his fields and use getters and setter for that

JavaBeans are Java classes that have properties. Think of
properties as private instance variables. Since they're private, the only way
they can be accessed from outside of their class is through methods in the class. The
methods that change a property's value are called setter methods, and the methods
that retrieve a property's value are called getter methods.

```
public class VariableStorage implements Serializable  {

    private String inString ;

    public String getInString() {
        return inString;
    }

    public void setInString(String inString) {
        this.inString = inString;
    }


}
```

Set the variable in you mail method by using

```
VariableStorage variableStorage = new VariableStorage();
variableStorage.setInString(inString);
```

Then use object Serialzation to serialize this object and in your other class deserialize this object.

In serialization an object can be represented as a sequence of bytes that includes the object's data as well as information about the object's type and the types of data stored in the object.

After a serialized object has been written into a file, it can be read from the file and deserialized that is, the type information and bytes that represent the object and its data can be used to recreate the object in memory.

If you want tutorial for this refer this link

http://javawithswaranga.blogspot.in/2011/08/serialization-in-java.html

[Get variable in other classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15999934/get-variable-in-other-classes/16000005#16000005)

D. **CommonUtilities**

You can make a class by your self which can contain common data which you frequently need in your project.

**Sample**

```
public class CommonUtilities {

    public static String className = "CommonUtilities";

}
```

E. **Passing Data through Intents**

Please refer this tutorial for this option of passing data.

http://shri.blog.kraya.co.uk/2010/04/26/android-parcel-data-to-pass-between-activities-using-parcelable-classes/

Answer (score 6):

you don't have to...

Just call newIntent() from second activity

```
Intent retData=new Intent();
```

Add data to pass back

```
putExtras (retData.putExtra("userName", getUsrName()));
```

Go ahead with setResult

```
setResult(RESULT_OK, retData);
```

And can then  finish

```
finish();
```

Answer (score 4):

**startActivityForResult()**

And here's a link from the SDK with more information:

http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/commontasks.html#opennewscreen

and scroll down to the part titled "Returning a Result from a Screen"

Answer (score 2):

I often use static variables in the calling activity with static setter methods to set them.

In this way I can change values in any activity at will, regardless of the exact flow of control between the various activities.

Note that this trick can only be used if you don't care about the
instantiation of more than one copy of the same activity (class) in the application,
yet I found this to be the easiest to implement, and I use it the most.

Comment: Not a great solution. This is going against Android's best practice. You can't guarantee an activity is not going to be killed and a new instance started by system.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do here is to put variable to a common class which is defined outside the scope

```
public class Utils 
{
    public static String mPosition;
}
```

inside your code (e.g. OnButtonClick etc...)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, 
ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
Utils.mPosition = mViewData.mPosition + "";
LogHelper.e(TAG, "before intent: " + Utils.mPosition);
startActivityForResult(intent, Keys.PICK_CONTACT);
```

inside the code of

@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        if (requestCode == Keys.PICK_CONTACT)
        {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
            {
                Uri contactData = data.getData();

```
            //you may use the variable here after intent result
            LogHelper.e(TAG, "after intent: " + Utils.mPosition);
....
```