# How to pass edit text data in form of string  to next activity?

Tags: android, string, button, android-activity

I am developing an android application in which i have taken two buttons and one edit text box.
i want to pass the data of edit text box in from of string to the next activity on click of one of the buttons, how can i pass the text to the next activity and  receive  that text in the new launched activity so could use the text  in that.

my code  for first activity is

```
EditText Urlis=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.entry);
final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ok);
final Intent i=new Intent(this , RSSReder.class);
final String choice=Urlis.getText().toString();

i.putExtra("key", choice);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivity(i);
    }    
});
```

and for called activity is

```
public class RSSReder extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

    public String RSSFEEDOFCHOICE;
    public final String tag = "RSSReader";
    private RSSFed feed = null;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    public void onCreate(Bundle abc) {
        super.onCreate(abc);
        setContentView(R.layout.next1);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        RSSFEEDOFCHOICE =i.getStringExtra("key");

        // go get our feed!
        feed = getFeed(RSSFEEDOFCHOICE);

        // display UI
        UpdateDisplay();

    }
}
```

is there anything i need to change or remove.

Comment: Try putting "String choice=Urlis.getText().toString();" inside the "onClick()" method. Also put "i.putExtra("key", choice);" in "onClick()" after it. Where you get the text at the moment, the chances are that you are setting 'choice' to be a blank String. You need to get the text when the user presses the Button to start the new Activity.

Comment: thanx Mister my code application is working it was really helpful

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After you have used `setContentView(...)` you need to reference your `EditText` and get the text such as...

```
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.my_edit_text);
String theText = et.getText().toString();
```

To pass it to another `Activity` you use an `Intent`. Example...

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, MyNewActivity.class);
i.putExtra("text_label", theText);
startActivity(i);
```

In the new Activity (in `onCreate()`), you get the Intent and retrieve the String...

```
public class MyNewActivity extends Activity {

    String uriString;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(...) {

        ...

        Intent i = getIntent();
        uriString = i.getStringExtra("text_label");

    }
}
```

Comment: +1, Its nice. Mister has mentioned about Sending and Receiving data as well.

Comment: `String theText = et.getText();` would throw a compile time error since `getText()` returns an `Editable` object. You have to call the `toString()` method as well.

Comment: @Octavian: Right you are sir! It's early in the morning here and I hadn't had my first cup of coffee. Error corrected, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Thanx Mister i passed the string and it worked but now  the problem is that the text of edit box is a url which i am passing i want it to be public is there a way i can get it before oncreate because in on create it removes the public modifier from it and the site is not accessed it is because the url is a rss feed which is to be passed further for parsing.

Comment: @Avi: So just make the string an instance variable and it will be accessible by all methods in your Activity. See the last code block in my answer.

Comment: Mister my code is not giving the desired output and it is showing no error i am giving the code in my question if you could suggest me something please

Answer (score 3):

Inside your Button's onClick Listener try the following,

```
String str=editText.getEditableText().toString();
```

Now use your intent,

```
Intent intent=new Intent(this,nextActivity.this);
intent.putExtra("editText_value",str);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use intents for the purpose. Here's a [tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html#explicitintents) for the same.

Also check [How to pass the values from one activity to previous activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124548/how-to-pass-the-values-from-one-activity-to-previous-activity)

Reading the contents of a String on Button click.

```
 EditText mText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext1);

Button mButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                          String text = mText.getText.toString();
                          Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
                          intent.putExtra("key", text);
                          startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use Intent to pass data to the next activity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,NextActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("sampleString", "youstringdata");
```

In NextActivity:

`String sampleData = getIntent().getExtras().getLong("sampleString");`