# Finishing an activity / Intent

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

I am making a that program is going into another activity to get some data, and then returning the data through intent to my main activity. The code I have at the moment does open a new activity, it gets and sends the data but seems to 'restart' my main activity when finish() is called.

Question: How do I stop my second activity restarting my main activity?

Main Activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(AndroidVideoPlayer.this, FileChooser.class);
intent.putExtra("dir", 1);
startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.d("CheckStartActivity","onActivityResult and resultCode = "+resultCode);
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    myPath = data.getStringExtra("stringPath");
    textEmpty.setText(myPath);
    myUri = Uri.parse(myPath);      
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, myUri);   
}
```

Secondary Activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FileChooser.this,AndroidVideoPlayer.class);
intent.putExtra("stringPath",intentPath1);
setResult(1,intent);
finish(); // <--- does close activity, but restarts main activity
```

Comment: when you finish an activity wants to go back to previous activity with result, do not create new intent, you should call getIntent; Intent intent = getIntent(); set the results as you did and finish

Answer (score 3):

That's how it is supposed to work. You need to override [onActivityResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult%28int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent%29) method of your main activity to get the stringPath from the intent.

Comment: @Jon So you're saying that onActivityResult is never called?

Comment: to add to Konstantin's answer, see another example here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124548/how-to-pass-the-values-from-one-activity-to-previous-activity

Answer (score 0):

Ok. You seem to be missing this line inside your onActivityResult definition.

> super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

Comment: I want it to return to the previous activity, but it seems to restart the activity rather than just go back to it because all of my interface gets reset.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your activity is being recreated again. Try overriding `onSaveInstanceState` and using the `savedInstanceState` on the `onCreate`. It should work.