# How can i send back data using finish?

Tags: android, android-intent

Like i can send data from one activity to another using this:

```
intent.putExtra("Name", Value);
```

how can i send data when i am using `finish()` to get back to the previous activity.

In my app from `Activity_A` i am going to `Activity_B`. In `Activity_B` i am marking a location on map, which gives me latitude and longitude. Then i want to use this lat and lng in `Activity_A`. But i don't want to get back to `Activity_A` using an intent, because i don't want to recreate the `Activity_A` since some data already filled will be lost.

Comment: save the value in a global variable or use shared pref

Comment: i have a problem with using global variable. if i am using it like this Activity_B.lat, Activity_A.lng. When i am in Activity_A, go to Activity_B and come back to Activity_A, close the app using home button, and reopen after 5 mins, i get null pointer exception since, the Activity_B which has this variable is destroyed

Comment: U can refer this link... it will help u for sure...http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/08/return-result-to-onactivityresult.html

Comment: you can use shared preference for it

Comment: have a look at that answer: [enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15641238/2160507

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass the values from one activity to previous activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124548/how-to-pass-the-values-from-one-activity-to-previous-activity)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

As you are using `intent.putExtra("Name", Value);`, use the same thing while finishing the activity also.

For ex.:

From activityA you call activityB like: `intent.putExtra("Name", Value);`

Now, instead of `startActivity()` use `startActivityForResult()`

And from activityB, while finishing the activity, call:

```
setResult(RESULT_OK);
```

Now in activityA, your `onActivityResult` will be called, which is like:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```

So inthis way you can handle it.

Comment: so i keep intent.putExtra("lat", lat); and then setResult(1, intent); then finish()??

Comment: and in onACtivityResult, data.getDoubleExtra("lat");

Comment: but 1 more thing. what if i press back button when i am in Activity_B. should i override onBackPress() in Activity_B and say resuldCode = 0?? is there a need or will android take care if nothing is sent in onActivityResult

Comment: If you want to disable the back button, you can.. For this same reason, in activityB, check inside onActivityResult, whether you have got correct request and result code. So if user presses back button, he result code will be something different.

Answer (score 27):

In Activity A:

```
// Add more, if you call different activities from Activity A
private static final REQUEST_GET_MAP_LOCATION = 0;

void doSomething() {
    ...
    startActivityForResult(theIntentYouUseToStartActivityB, REQUEST_GET_MAP_LOCATION);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_GET_MAP_LOCATION && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        int latitude = data.getIntExtra("latitude", 0);
        int longitude = data.getIntExtra("longitude", 0);
        // do something with B's return values
    }
}
```

In Activity B:

```
...
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, 
    new Intent().putExtra("latitude", latitude).putExtra("longitude", longitude));
finish();
...
```

Comment: i have a case where, Activity_A call Activity_B which inturn calls Activity_C and finish();... Now if i call finish() on Activity_C i get to Activity_A, but here in onActiviyResult, it is not entering the if block which you gave. thats expected because From Activity_B to Activity_C i am just using startActivity(intent). HOw to solve this case?? thank you

Comment: @Archie.bpgc: When you call Activity_C in B, do you `setResult` before calling `finish`?

Comment: No i wasn't using anything except Intent(Activity_B, ACtivity_C), startActivity(intent) and finish();

Comment: but i then changed startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

Comment: i thought no use in setResult in Activity_B because i dont have lat, lng values here, they are in Activity_C and moreover when coming3back from ACtivity_C to ACtivity_A i won't pass through ACtivity_B, since its finished

Comment: @Archie.bpgc: If you get the values in Activity_C, Activity_B will have to wait for Activity_C to finish and then pass the values back to Activity_A. So, B need to `startActivityForResult` C and *not* finish yet. B can finish in `onActivityResult`, after putting the values from C back to its own result.

Comment: so i can startActivityForResult in B to go to C, then in C i setResult and finish(). Again in B in onActivityResult take those values and call finish() using these values in setResult. Then i will end up in A getting values from B, which actually are values from C?? am i right?

Comment: @Archie.bpgc: Exactly, that's the plan.

Answer (score 10):

Call your `Activity_B` with `startActivityForResult()`, from your `Activity_A`:

```
 //Starting a new Intent
 Intent nextScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity_B.class);
 // starting new activity
 startActivityForResult(nextScreen,1000);
```

Once you finished working on the `Activity_B`, you call `setResult()` to set the data, followed by `finish()` like this

```
 //Starting the previous Intent
 Intent previousScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity_A.class);
 //Sending the data to Activity_A 
 previousScreen.putExtra("Bla"," Blabla"); 
 setResult(1000, previousScreen);
 finish();
```

This will bring you back to your previous `Activity_A`.

In `Activity_A`, override `onActivityResult()`.

```
 @Override  
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)     
  {
     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
     String bla = data.getStringExtra("Bla");       
  }
```

Found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15641238/2160507)

Answer (score 1):

use `startActivityForResult` to start B and `setResult` before B `finish` and handle `onAcitivityResult` in A