# Send data to activity which is running in background

Tags: android, android-activity

Having trouble passing data between activities.
ListActivity is collecting data and when back button is pressed returns to MainActivity and then want to get that data via onResume method but I don't get anything.

How can this problem be solved?

ListActivity.java

```
    @Override
public void finish() {
    i = new Intent(ArrayListActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    i.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Constants.TAG_SELECTED_PRODUCT_LIST, selected_list);
    super.finish();
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
    @Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras().getBundle(Constants.TAG_SELECTED_PRODUCT_LIST);
    if(extras != null) {
        selected_list = extras.getParcelableArrayList(Constants.TAG_SELECTED_PRODUCT_LIST);


        myListView.setAdapter(new ProductAdapter(MainActivity.this,
                    R.layout.array_lisviewt_item_row, selected_list));
    }
}
```

Comment: What flags are you using for your activities? Single Task, Single top etc.?

Comment: Actually.. none :/ i'm newbie

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to start your second activity from the first one via the [`startActivityForResult(...)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int,%20android.os.Bundle%29) method.

This method allows you to transport results from a launched activity back to it's launching activity.

From the documentation:

> Launch an activity for which you would like a result when it finished.
>   When this activity exits, your [onActivityResult()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult%28int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent%29) method will be
>   called with the given requestCode. Using a negative requestCode is the
>   same as calling startActivity(Intent) (the activity is not launched as
>   a sub-activity).

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to start the activity with [startActivityForResult()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int,%20android.os.Bundle%29) and override [onActivityResult()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult%28int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent%29) to handle the data you return from the second Activity.

Check out this [article](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html) on the Android developers site for more info.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you should

- Call your `ListActivity` with [startActivityForResult()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int,%20android.os.Bundle%29), from your `MainActivity`.
- Once you finished working on the `ListActivity`, you call [setResult()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult%28int,%20android.content.Intent%29) to set the data, followed by [finish()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29).

This will bring you back to your previous `MainActivity`. So how do you retrieve the data set by your `ListActivity`?

- In `MainActivity`, override [onActivityResult()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult%28int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent%29).

There's a brief explanation of this mechanism in [Starting Activities and Getting Results](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities).