# Android - How to navigate activity stack/tasks

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, activity-stack

I have 3 `Activities`, `Activity A, B, & C`. From `ActivityA`, I click on a `button` to launch `ActivityB` and within `ActivityB` I click another `button` to launch `ActivityC`.

I am trying to figure out the proper way to return to `ActivityA` from `ActivityC` with optional return to `ActivityB` from `ActivityC`.

If I am in `ActivityC` and click the home `button` I want to return to `ActivityB`, but if I click my 'save' `button` I want to finish `ActivityC` & `ActivityB` and show `ActivityA`.

How can I accomplish this?

***Answer Edit***: As krishna murali's suggested in his answer, he was about 99% of the way there. These two flags did the trick `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` & `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`

Comment: Use `startActivityForResult()` and pass the values back to the parent activity during `finsh()` call and decide whether the previous parent should be finished or not based on the button click. [Here is the example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12293980/4596556)

Comment: I think he not aiming at passing back the result. He want to return to ActivityA on the click of button in the activityC.@MadhukarHebbar

Comment: @krishnamurali He has two cases (Save and Home). One for Activity A and one for Activity  B.

Comment: I was hoping to do the logic in ActivityC and depending on the situation clear ActivityC and optionally ActivityB depending on the click listener.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Click of your button to return to ActivityA from ActivityC.
Use this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityA.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

This will clear all the activities on top of ActivityA.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, this appears to be working. It appears that its starting a new instance of ActivityA, not returning as if I called finish() in ActivityB.

Comment: you could use launcherMode = singleTask or singleTop within your manifest

Comment: Actually, i added Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP as well as CLEAR_TOP and it worked as expected! Thank you everyone.