# Get textfield's value from one activity to another

Tags: android-activity

I have two activities

```
Class MainActivity{
     //has a single button and
    //invokes SubActivity
}


Class SubActivity{
   //This activity several textfields
}
```

While `SubActivity` is alive, I press back button and go back to MainActivity.
When I go back to `MainActivity` again, I would like to get the textfield values from the `MainActivity`. I tried using context but it doesn't seem to work. Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124548/how-to-pass-the-values-from-one-activity-to-previous-activity

Answer (score 0):

You either have to pass them in a bundle with the intent to start the activity, write them to shared preferences, or put them in sqlite database. It's not possible to simply read data from another activity.

Comment: I do write them with shared preferences but I can't read them back from the MainActivity after the SubActivity closes.