# Working with Intents android Studio

Tags: android

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent fi = getIntent();
    if (fi.getExtras() != null) {
        Rating = fi.getStringExtra("KEY_rating");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Thanks for giving us " + Rating + " stars", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Code lower down.

```
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //save users values
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    savedInstanceState.putDouble(SAVED_VALUE, dblInput);
}
```

I had an error on `protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`
and `public void onCreate(Bundle values)`
It is fixed now, This is the correct way of getting intents from another activity.

Comment: it is a duplicate method declaration. The signature it's the same

Comment: **Which** error do you get? Please add a quote to your question.

Comment: You are duplicating the same method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `onCreate` is duplicated. I think that you are extending a class with `protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` method and a interface with `public void onCreate(Bundle values)` method.

If that is tha case, than you should put all your code with the apropriates modifications in the implementation with public visibility and delete the implementation with the protected visibility.

If not, choose the best visibility implementation and put all your code there, deleting de other one.

Comment: sorry, I don't follow :/

Answer (score 2):

Method `onCreate` is duplicated.

Answer (score 2):

> sorry, I don't follow :/ – martin drap

Try it:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent fi = getIntent();
    if (fi.getExtras() != null) {
        Rating = fi.getStringExtra("KEY_rating");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Thanks for giving us " + Rating + " stars", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    if (savedInstanceState != null){
        dblInput = savedInstanceState.getDouble("");
    }
}
```

Comment: that got rid of the error but I still cant get the saved instance to be shown in the editText on return from second activity

Comment: to solve this problem, try the post [How to pass the values from one activity to previous activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124548/how-to-pass-the-values-from-one-activity-to-previous-activity).

Answer (score 0):

You cant have two method with same signature in a class : so rename one of them

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Intent fi = getIntent();
if (fi.getExtras() != null) {
    Rating = fi.getStringExtra("KEY_rating");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Thanks for giving us " +
       Rating + " stars", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}


}
//@Override
public void onCreate_duplicate(Bundle values) {
if (values != null){
    dblInput = values.getDouble("");
}
}
```

Comment: I tried that before but I get an error that the method I renamed is never used

Comment: Method 'onCreate_duplicate(android.os.Bundle)' is never used

Comment: This is not an error, its a warning that your code contains something that no one needs (anymore). You can ignore that or delete the unused code.

Comment: I ran the app and the code doesn't work.
maybe I have something wrong with this part?
`public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle values) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(values);
        values.putDouble("", dblInput);
    }`