# How to come back to First activity without its onCreate() called

Tags: android, android-activity, navigation

I have 3 activity . Activity A ,Activity B, Activity C.
This is the flow  A->B->C.
Now i want to come to activity A from C .(i.e C->A) without getting its onCreate() called of Activity A.

so far my code is:But it will call onCreate() of ActivityA.
I want to call Restart().

```
Intent intent=new Intent(ActivityC.this,ActivityA.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
```

Comment: I don't know how to avoid called `onCreate` **but** you can put a **flag** (and once it true skip onCreate method using return;)

Comment: You could add an `extra` to your `intent`, which you retrieve in the `onCreate` and write a condition about the code, which should not be executed in this case.

Comment: android fragment is the best option for this

Comment: While moving to C from B, finish B. Now when you will finish C you will come back to A by default and onCreate wont be called.

Comment: @Rohit5k2 i have a condition here , i can't go to B .(In real case scenario i have more 10 activity) so its not possible to put finish statement on every one of them

Comment: @AsfK what flag can you elaborate a little

Comment: You can return to your activity (A) with data (pass data between activities), put a boolean flag... see this for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124548/how-to-pass-the-values-from-one-activity-to-previous-activity

Comment: Some explanation on WHY it happens: (From Android Docs) Note: If the launch mode of the designated activity is "standard", it too is removed from the stack and a new instance is launched in its place to handle the incoming intent. That's because a new instance is always created for a new intent when the launch mode is "standard". Link: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack.html

Answer (score 11):

Two cases:

1. If you want to keep other activities live and just want to bring A to front, just use intent flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT.
2. If you don't want to clear all activities and want existing instance of A at top, then use intent flags FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP and FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP.

Note : If you use only FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP, then onCreate will be called.

Answer (score 5):

Keep `android:launchMode="singleTask"` in manifest at activity declaretion

An Activity with singleTask launchMode is allowed to have only one instance in the system
If instance already exists, i will not call 'onCreate' it will call 'onNewIntent' method.
See http://androidsrc.net/android-activity-launch-mode-example/ for better understand about launch modes.

Answer (score 2):

Although setting the launch mode to `singleTask` will work, use of that launch mode is discouraged.  The [documentation for launch mode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) indicates `singleTask` is "not recommended for general use".

The desired behavior can be achieved using Intent flags `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`:

```
    Intent intent=new Intent(ActivityC.this,ActivityA.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
```

Activity A will not be recreated and will receive the intent via `onNewIntent()`.

Comment: I can confirm with `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`, onCreate is call, with  `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`, onNewIntent is called. I don't know why it does this way, not mentioned in docs. I thought with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` should trigger onNewnIntent.

Answer (score 0):

Use SingleTask launch mode for Activity A.

New intent will be delivered to existing instance.