# How to send back value between several Activities on Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm trying use a value retrieved from Activity3 to Activity1.
This is my flow:

> Activity1 calls Activity2 → Activity2.finish(), call Activity3 →
>   Activity3.doSomethingAndGetValue() → Activity3.finish() →
>   Activity1.useDoSomethingAndGetValue();

I can not find the way to send back the values from Activity3 to Activity1; Even using startActivityForResult() because Activity2 was already destroyed by that time.

I tried to use a serializable interface and pass this as extra value on the intent, but this solution only works with the object passed is a static which doesn't allow me to do any change in the current member variables on Activity 1.

Besides, I've tried all these options without success:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17306696/3217203

(I'm not allow to use shared preferences for this)

Does anyone has any idea?

Note: I can't add eventBus, I know would be great and way easier but the architecture didn't allow me.

Comment: [EventBus](http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/) seems applicable here

Comment: you could try `startActivityForResult` but an event bus as @cricket_007 suggested might be better

Comment: BTW: I can't add eventBus, I know would be great and way easier but the architecture didn't allow me.

Comment: `startActivityForResult()` with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT` exists exactly for this purpose. See answer from @Nir Duan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might like to make use of the intent flag **FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT** as described in [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) when starting activities 2 and 3.

**Code**

```
Activity 1 -> startActivityForResult(activityB,0);
Activity 2 -> activityCintent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT); startActivity(activityCintent); finish();
Activity 3 -> setresult(10); finish();
Activity 1 -> if(result==10) {dofunction(); }
```

this is the logic of FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT. First you start an activity for result, new activity sends this intent to another new activity until you set result.

Answer (score 0):

If you the data requirement is limited to the three activities as in your description, I would suggest, not finish activity2 before going to activity3. Instead, make use of `startActivityForResult()` the activities. When returning from activity3 to activity2, call finish() and then return to activity1.

If the above solution is not acceptable, try the following 2 approaches:

**(1)** You could use variables with an application context.
For this, first create an Application class say MyApp.java,

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

private String data;

public String getData() {
       return data;
   }

   public void setData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
   }
}
```

Now, add this class as `android:name` for the application tag in manifest,

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.tony.myapp">

<application
    android:name=".MyApp"
    .....>
```

In the Activity3,

```
String data = "I am BATMAN!!";
MyApp myApp = (MyApp) getApplicationContext();
myApp.setData(data);
```

Then, all you need to do in the Activity1 is,

```
MyApp myApp = (MyApp) getApplicationContext();
String data = myApp.getData();
```

---

**(2)** If you have simple key-value pairs that you want to persist different instances of the app, use [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html#WriteSharedPreference).

Answer (score 0):

U can Use setter and getter pojo class

Setvalues from activity3 and use them in activity 1.

> ```
> public class MyPojo   {
>    private static String value;
>    public static String   getValue() {
>     return value; 
>        }
>      public static void setValue(String value) 
>      { 
>            MyPojo.value = value; 
>       }
>  }
> ```

In the Activity3,

> MyPojo.setValue("this is activity3");

Then in the Activity1 ,

> MyPojo.getValue();

Comment: Okay, you would need to pass the POJO between the activities, though. Unless you suggest a singleton?

Answer (score 0):

As Tony suggested you can use the App class (which is a singleton), but I would create another singleton class, specific for your purpose. Like this...

```
public class Singleton {
    private static Singleton INSTANCE = null;
    private String aValue;
    private int bValue;
    private Object cValue;

    private Singleton(){

    }

    public static Singleton getInstance(){     
        if(INSTANCE == null){
            INSTANCE = new Singleton();
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }
    //Setters and getters here
}
```

In that way you can get the same instance (by using the static method `Singleton.getInstance()`) in all your activities and change/read its values as you need.