# Android: How to maintain set data in the list view

Tags: android

In **Activity A**, I click a button to go to **Activity B**. I bring data using `Bundle` back to the **Activity A** and I managed to change a `String value` in the `ListView`. Then I go to another **Activity C** to manipulate another data. The problem is, when I get back again to the **Activity A**, the data from the **Activity C** is reflected in the `ListView`, but the previous data from the **Activity B** is gone.

Here's a code to the **Activity B** from the **Activity A**.

```
private void gotoRepeatWeeklyOptionActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(CreateNewAlarmActivity.this, RepeatWeeklyOptionActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

This one is the method from the **Activity A** to the **Activity C**.

```
private void openAlarmToneOptionDialog() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(CreateNewAlarmActivity.this, ChooseAlarmToneActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

And this is a code that leads to the **Activity A** from the **Activity B**.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, CreateNewAlarmActivity.class);

    ArrayList<Integer> repeatStatusIntList = new ArrayList<>();
    intent.putExtra(Keys.OPTION, Keys.OPTION_REPEAT);

    if(cbRepeatEveryDay.isChecked()) {
        super.onBackPressed();
        intent.putExtra(Keys.VALUE, Keys.EVERY_DAY);
        Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.alarm_will_repeat_every_day), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if(allUnchecked()) {
        super.onBackPressed();
        intent.putExtra(Keys.VALUE, Keys.NO_REPEAT);
        Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.alarm_will_never_repeat), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        for(int i=0; i<repeatStatusList.size(); i++) {
            super.onBackPressed();
            if(repeatStatusList.get(i).isChecked()) {
                repeatStatusIntList.add(getRepeatStatusInt(repeatStatusList.get(i)));
                intent.putIntegerArrayListExtra(Keys.KEY_REPEAT_STATUS_INTEGERS_LIST, repeatStatusIntList);
            }

            intent.putExtra(Keys.VALUE, Keys.ON);
        }
        Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.alarm_will_repeat) + getString(R.string.every) +
                getAllRepeatDays(repeatStatusList), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_OK);
    finish();
}
```

Finally, this is a code from the **Activity C**, which leads back to the **Activity A**.

```
    btnSelectTone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CreateNewAlarmActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(Keys.OPTION, Keys.OPTION_ALARM_TONE);
            intent.putExtra(Keys.VALUE, ringtone);

            if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                mediaPlayer.release();
            }
            startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_OK);
            finish();
        }
    });
```

Here's a sample screen from the `Activity A`.
[image]

Comment: I guess you got confused with the usage of startActivityForResult. Can you tell what exactly are you trying to achieve at the end. May be there is much more simpler solution for your problem.

Comment: I just want to update the items on the `ListView` in the Activity A by configuring each from Activity B and C

Comment: I uploaded a screen shot, so this might help you understand a little bit better..

Comment: Probably I need to use `SharedPreferences` class to maintain data, but I don't know how. Any good references or answers please?

Comment: why you don't use singleton pattern ? one static object that handle your data

Comment: singleton pattern for the Activity A, you mean?

Comment: no, singletons is very bad idea

Comment: What you are trying to achieve must be done on fragments instead of activities. Adding activities for small tasks will overload your app. I got a bit of what you are trying, if u can upload screenshots of activities b and c too, then i guess providing solution would be much easier

Comment: @MohammedAtif Got it! I should do that way. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what Atif has suggested is one solution which is most desirable in your case.
Else you can use Shared Preferences like below. Get the SP instance and commit the data you want to share in editor

```
// We need an Editor object to make preference changes.
      // All objects are from android.context.Context
      SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
      editor.putBoolean("silentMode", mSilentMode);

      // Commit the edits!
      editor.commit();
    }
```

And this is how you can retrieve the shared pref data

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
       boolean silent = settings.getBoolean("silentMode", false);
```

Personally i would suggest you to surf more on developer.android.com or visit below link
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

In future if you have large amount of data then above solution wont work.

Please follow below link for more options

[How to pass the values from one activity to previous activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124548/how-to-pass-the-values-from-one-activity-to-previous-activity)