# Click ImageView within a ListView ListItem and get the position?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, listitem

Currently, when the ListItem is clicked I grab its position and pass it to my StopsScheduleActiviy. I would like to detect when the ImageView of that ListItem is clicked so that I can launch my MapActivity instead and pass it the position.

Basically: Click the ImageView launch MapsActivity, otherwise click anywhere else on ListItem launch StopsScheduleActivity. In Both cases I need the position. How can I do this?

Here is my current onItemClick listener.

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, StopsScheduleActivity.class);
    myIntent.putExtra("stop", stops.get(position));

    startActivity(myIntent);

    Log.i("Winnipeg Bus", "Stop item #" + id + " clicked.");
}
```

Here is my ListView with a map for an ImageView that I want to listen to for clicks. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: position of onItemClick doesn't give the position?

Comment: Make custom adapter in this on GetView() method write ImageView's onClick().. And do what you want...

Comment: @LalitPoptani It does, but how do I know the ImageView was clicked?

Comment: @user370305 Can you elaborate a bit, perhaps with the some code in an answer. Thanks.

Comment: Look at this tutorial [Android Series: Custom ListView items and adapters](http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/) in this adapter's getView method you can write imageView.setOnClick() and your stuff..

Comment: Try this and let me know what happen.. :-)

Comment: @user370305 Thanks for you help. I checked the link, but I don't see where I should set the imageView's onClickListener. I just tried to do it in the getView(...) method of my custom array adapter but get the following error when trying to launch the MapActivity: `Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?` ...Actually, in hindsight the click did register...

Comment: Actually, setting `myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);` worked. Thanks! Post an answer below detailing what you told me and I'll accept. Thanks again.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For **ImageView's Click You have to make a custom adapter for your listview**.

And in adpater's `getView()` method just write a `imageView's onClick()`, And start your new activity from that imageview's onClick().

For custom list just look at this tutorial [Android Series: Custom ListView items and adapters](http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/) ..

Comment: Thanks again. For those interested see the main questions comments for more info. Also, Arslan's answer shows code implementation very similar to what I ended up using.

Comment: How to pass a result back from the new activity? How to use onActivityResult() here?

Comment: @Jas - use `setResult()` method set Intent in it. and get this intent in `onActivityResult()`. Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920306/sending-data-back-to-the-main-activity-in-android

Comment: I can write `onActivityResult()` in Activity only right? If i am firing the intent from my adapter class, where should i write the `onActivityResult()` ?

Comment: In the Activity which calls your `Adapter` and you are using context to `startActivityForResult()`..

Answer (score 26):

In you Custom Adapter `getView()` method , when you are init the `ImageView`. Add position as a tag for image view. So each time when new `ImageView` will appear it will hold its position in his tag. Then just add the `OnClickListener()` in `getView()`.

`OnClickListener(View view)` contains the view which was clicked by user. So when user will click any image view in the list. Then it will be passed to `OnClickListener(View view)` as a clicked view. And we know that our `ImageView` contains the position as a tag. So the tag can tell us that this `ImageView` is for ? position. :)

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        
    if(convertView == null){
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false);
    }

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.videoListImage);
    imageView.setTag(new Integer(position));
    imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "ImageView clicked for the row = "+view.getTag().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

You will get the clicked `ImageView` position.

Answer (score 4):

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    System.out.println("getView " + position + " " + convertView);
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(conText).inflate(
            R.layout.gridgoggle, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.imageView1.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt((mData
        .get(position).get("image"))));

    holder.imageView1.setId(position);
    holder.imageView1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int id = v.getId();
            //here id is position.
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, StopsScheduleActivity.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("stop", id);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In three simple steps:

1 In your adapter method getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent):

```
ImageView imageview =(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
imageview.setTag(new Integer(position));
```

2 In `layout.xml` add the method `onClick()` on the `ImageView`

3 `implements onClick()` method and retrieves the index by `view.getTag()`

Comment: Please know the usage of the inline formatting `\`like this\``. I'll edit your question