# Return result to MainActivity after after adding two numbers in the SecondActivity

Tags: android, android-intent

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sending data back to the Main Activity in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920306/sending-data-back-to-the-main-activity-in-android)

I need logic for adding two numbers in the second activity and return the result to Main Activity? 
I want it to be done through Intents concept in Android.