# How to restart activity using intent?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am making an android app which plays mp3 files. I am launching the mp3 playing activity from within another activity using intent:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(ListViewA.this,mp3player.class);
                intent.putExtra("feed",gh);
                i.setFlags(0);
                i.setPackage(null);
                //intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
                startActivity(intent);
```

Now when the user selects another song from a list, I want to close the previous instance of the mp3player activity and start a new one using the intent code (above). How do I go about doing that? Thanks.

Comment: basically how many activity you have???

Comment: @rickky I have 2 activites: a main activity and a child activity.

Comment: so you are selecting a song in listviewA from there you are calling mp3eplayer activity am i right so you want when you are back to listviewA there you wanna close mp3player activity right????

Comment: @rickky yes, that is exactly what i am trying to do

Comment: i have updated my answer please check it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `startActivity` use `startActivityForResult(intent, PLAY_SONG)` then you can call `finishActivity(PLAY_SONG)` where PLAY_SONG is a constant number.

class member

```
private static final int PLAY_SONG
```

And then

```
finishActivity(PLAY_SONG);
Intent intent=new Intent(ListViewA.this,mp3player.class);
intent.putExtra("feed",gh);
i.setFlags(0);
i.setPackage(null);
startActivityForResult(intent, PLAY_SONG)
```

Comment: I am new to android, can you please elaborate?

Comment: You can refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920306/sending-data-back-to-the-main-activity-in-android for this.

Comment: So what happen now is the mp3player class window is still in foreground when finished playing?

Comment: When i select a new song, the previous does not stop playing.

Comment: So you need to do what I answered above, let me edited a little bit.

Comment: 2 instances of the mp3player activity are created, both play different songs. no change from earlier code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29038/discussion-between-hoan-nguyen-and-vergil-corleone)

Answer (score 0):

Hey its very simple Instead of calling Intent from `Mp3Playeractivity` call `finish()` when you are pressing the back button by implementing

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
finish();
}
```

which will cause `close` your `MpeplayerActivity`

Comment: but i do not want to close the music when the back button is pressed.