# Check If Activity Has Been Called for Result

Tags: android, android-activity, startactivityforresult

Is it possible to know if some activity has been called for result, using `startActivityForResult()` or if was only started using `startActivity()`?

I need to control this, if its called for result the behaviour will be different.

Answer (score 182, accepted):

When your activity was started just by `startActivity()` a `getCallingActivity()` method in target activity will return `null`.

When it was called by `startActivityForResult()` it will return name of calling activity.

See Docs for [`getCallingActivity()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getCallingActivity%28%29):

> Return the name of the activity that invoked this activity. This is
>   who the data in `setResult()` will be sent to. You can use this
>   information to validate that the recipient is allowed to receive the
>   data.
>
> > Note: if the calling activity is not expecting a result (that is it
> >     did not use the `startActivityForResult(Intent, int)` form that
> >     includes a request code), then the calling package will be null.
>
> **Returns**
>
> The ComponentName of the activity that will receive your reply, or null if none.

Comment: If you start the activity with: FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK, it doesn't work :( (I had to start the login activity out of context in an error handler). Any other ideas? Thanks!

Comment: this doesn't work if the activity is started with a fragment:  fragment.getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);

Comment: @MarioLenci It works correctly for me. No matter whether I start it from activity or fragment.

Comment: @MarioLenci because when you are in a fragment, you don’t have to call `getActivity().startActivityFor…` from a fragment you have to do `startActivityForResult` directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse a boolean with put extra inside an intent.

```
//First Activity
Intent i = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActiviy.class);   
boolean isForResult = true;
i.putExtra("for-result", isForResult);
```

Then on Second Activity get the value:

```
//Second Activity
boolean isForResult = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("for-result" , false);
```

This way you know with a global boolean if you start an activity for get a result. If you don't put a boolean extra the default value will be false. Wich means.

```
//Not necesary at all.
boolean isForResult = false;
```

You don't need to parse a false boolean.