# How can I close app using back button in the second activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

Lets say I have a a main activity `FirstActivity` (when I press the back button here, it just closes the app) and I have another activity called `SecondActivity` (FirstActivity goes to this when user is logged in). Now when I press the back button, it goes to `FirstActivity` instead of closing the app. Is there any way I can just close the app from `SecondActivity`, ignoring any Activity on the back stack? The callback method I use to close the app in my `SecondActivity`:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    finish();   
}
```

Comment: Read about startactivitywithresult and onactivityresult, or something like that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best thing to do is when you start the `SecondActivity` in the `FirstActivity`, do this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
finish(); // finish FirstActivity
```

Using this, the `FirstActivity` will be destroyed when the `SecondActivity` is created.

Comment: The finish(); does the job entirely. This was exactly what I wanted. Thanks.

Comment: including `finish()` in the `FirstActivity` destroys the activity and makes sure that it is not reached using the back button. Thus also conservers memory.

Comment: Don't forget to do a final clean up of resources you used.

Comment: @LuisAlberto Could you be more specific? I'm new to Android.

Comment: onFinish() call the method onDestroy(), so there you need to clean the mess you did literally :P. For example: You opened a stream on onCreate(), then you close it to avoid memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like [<kbd>startActivityForResult</kbd>](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int)) kind of like what I had to do in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18526333/how-to-display-an-alert-to-a-different-activity), or you could do what I've done here:

```
public class FirstActivity {
    public static boolean close = false;    

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        if (close) {
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public class SecondActivity {

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        FirstActivity.close = true;
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: @LuisAlberto It doesn't matter. I suggested `startActivityForResult` as well as a flag. They both work fine and a flag could be nice if he only wants the back button to close the app completely in certain situations (change `FirstActivity.close` when he wants). Otherwise, SMR's answer will work for him.

Comment: Yeah, your answer is good, but that's why a finish() method was made, but in some cases using a flag would be the best option. :-)