# Retrieving data between more than one Activities

Tags: android

I am new to android application I have a task is that i should pass data from activity A->Activity B and should pass data between Activity B-----------> Activity C Same way I should get data from Activity C-------> Activity A please tell the scenario or send an example for me

Comment: Your question does not show any effort on your part. Have you considered passing `bundle` objects via `Intent`?

Comment: Please read documentation for `startActivityForResult`

Answer (score 0):

Try two options
1). Intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.putExtra("KEY", "VALUE");
startActivity(intent);
```

2). `Shared Preference` if the data is shared between all activities.

Answer (score 0):

`Intent` is what you needed:

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
mIntent.putExtra("key", "value");
startActivity(mIntent);
```

The above code starts `ActivityB` and sends the data along with it, to ActivityB `(from mIntent.putStringExtra("key", "value");`)

You can also see the different prototypes of this from [here.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#pubmethods)

On the next activity, `ActivityB`, you can get the data sent by code below (write it inside onCreate() in `ActivityB`):

```
Intent mIntent = getIntent();
String data_recieved = mIntent.getStringExtra("key"); \\ here key is same as mentioned in previous activity from where you reached here.
```

Comment: But i want to pass data from Activity C to Activity A and also call Activity A

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data from A to B by using intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity.class);
intent.putExtra("name", "value");
startActivity(intent);
```

You can return back value using `onActivtyResult()` or by storing it in

> shared preferences

If you are using `onActivtyResult()` method you need to start activty for result using : `startActivityForResult()` method

You can check this for sending data back
[send data back to activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920306/sending-data-back-to-the-main-activity-in-android)