# Android - intent to new activity to update the main one without replication

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

First of all, I searched a lot but I dont know what i'm doing it wrong!.

I have MainActivity which has a Listview and add button, the a button take you to addnewActivity which you can enter new items to the listview in the MainActivity and take you back to it.

Now, the problem is, every time I add new item I get new it in a new instance of the MainActivity which doesnt contain the update of the open before it! (First new item wont be visible the second time I add new item, each in different one! ).

All I need is, One MainActivity every time I add to it, so no replication (going back from it should close the app) and the data always move from the older to the newest.

- I use startActivity(intent); to more between them
- using back button from the addnewActivity should back to latest MainActivity.

I believe this is how normal app should behave!.
Thanks

update:

my add new item button

```
private void additembutt() {
Intent intent = new Intent(this, add.class);
int idx = Items.size(); //this is the List<items> (to get the the last postion)
intent.putExtra(ID_X, idx); //newPosition

startActivity(intent);
//startActivityForResult(intent, 1); //not using this anymore, didnt work
//finish();
}
```

and on the add.class

```
Intent intent = getIntent();

idx = intent.getIntExtra(MainActivity.ID_X, -1); //take the id

Intent intentback = new Intent(add.this, MainActivity.class);

//read the user inputs and put them in msges like this as well
intentback.putExtra(ID_X, msg_idx); //Position
intentback.putExtra(ID_MESSAGE, msg_name);

startActivity(intentback);
finish();
```

Comment: After you add the new item, do you have a line `startActivity(mainIntentVariableArg)` ?

Comment: what i do is send the entered value back to the main activity by
intentback.putExtra(ID_MESSAGE3, psin_value);
startActivity(intentback);

btw usually I had the last mainactivity I go back to with all the modification but i dont know what I have mess  :\

Comment: can you add your relevant code. that would help

Comment: okay ill update the question above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `startActivity(mainIntent)` you should be using `startActivityForResult()`

Referenced from another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920306/sending-data-back-to-the-main-activity-in-android)

Comment: I'v tried that, the mainActivity stopped getting data from the second one! maybe because i used .putExtra to send them together ??

Comment: You see, the `finish()` which you have after the line `startActivityForResult()` destroys the `MainActivity` bcoz of which the `MainActivity` stops getting data from the second one.

Comment: I think I fixed it :), I didnt know that I can receive the data im sending inside onActivityResult :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try removing

```
startActivity(intentback);
```

And see if you get desired result. For more information [refere to this](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html)