# Need to got to previous activity when button is clicked in android

Tags: android, android-activity

This is my part of a code.when i click the button"play" i need to take it to the previous activity which is the main activity.Have tried this code but this is not working.Iam new to android ..Plz help.Thanks in advance!!

```
                    Button play;
                    case R.id.playid:
        Intent i = getIntent();
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(i);
              @Override
      public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();
    startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending data back to the Main Activity in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920306/sending-data-back-to-the-main-activity-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the launch modes for `activity` inside `manifest`.  Unless specified a custom behavior, your activities called one after the other will form a stack structure.
This will help: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

In order to return to the previous activity, you just need to finish the current one then, which is done by `finish();` or `context.finish();`  where `context` can be "`this`" or declared exclusively.
Recommend you to read this page, the whole:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29

Also, for `onBackPressed`, in your case, you may not override the default implementation:

> Called when the activity has detected the user's press of the back
>   key. The default implementation simply finishes the current activity,
>   but you can override this to do whatever you want.

Source: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed()

Answer (score 1):

You need to use startActivityForResult ,in this process you start activity B From A and when B finished b clear from top of android stack

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(i, 1);
```

and in SecondActivity

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra("result",result);
setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);     
finish();
```

Update: 
i forgot main point.
and in first Activity

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

 if (requestCode == 1) {

 if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){      
     String result=data.getStringExtra("result");          
 }
 if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {    
     //Write your code if there's no result
     } 
   }
 }
```

and u also can send another result in Second Activity such bellow :

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, returnIntent);        
finish();
```

Comment: There are two activities a and b.After b is completed i need to go back to "a" when button is clicked.@Bigoloo

Comment: Where the first two lines should be added?Either in first or second activity @bigoloo

Comment: hi first two line should add to where u want to start Second Activity @anusha startActivity and startActivityForResult is same but in startActivityForResult in second Activity u create an intent and set resuklt on it and finish it and i forgot most important part