# How does the Intent passed from the onActivityResult argument work with my application?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, **Intent data**){
        super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, **data**);

        switch (reqCode) {
            case (PICK_CONTACT) :
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

                    Uri contactData = **data**.getData();
                    Cursor c =  getContentResolver().query(**contactData**, null, null, null, null);
                    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                        String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                        // TODO Whatever you want to do with the selected contact name.
                       //ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                       //Picasso.with(this).load("https://cms-assets.tutsplus.com/uploads/users/21/posts/19431/featured_image/CodeFeature.jpg").into(imageView);
                        FragmentManager FM = getFragmentManager();
                        FragmentTransaction FT = FM.beginTransaction();
                        FragmentActivity F1 = new FragmentActivity();



                        FT.add(R.id.frame_layout, F1);
                        FT.commit();

                    }
                }
                break;
        }

    }
```

Can someone explain how the `data` variable in the `onActivityResult` argument is used to make this code work?

I see that the variable is used to call `getData()`  but I'm confused as to how this variable is connected to the Intent outside of this method. 
Furthermore, what exactly does calling `data.getData()` do ?

Basically I'm trying to understand this snippet of the code

```
 public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (reqCode) {
            case (PICK_CONTACT) :
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

                    Uri contactData = data.getData();
                    Cursor c =  getContentResolver().query(contactData, null, null, null, null);
```

Could anyone help me make sense of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data variable is the Intent that you have specified in the closing Activity. When you want to finish the Activity you called with `startActivityForResult()`, you should call setResult().

As first parameter, you should set the result code (`RESULT_OK`, `RESULT_CANCELED`, ...). You can also add a second one which should be an Intent and which will contain the information you want to receive in `onActivityResult()`. And that is the data variable in `onActivityResult()`.

If you want to know more about `getData()`, you can check this : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getData()

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here : [Click me and than the first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920306/sending-data-back-to-the-main-activity-in-android)

At the link you can see that you can give the `Intent data` a bundle or extras, which you get with your getData() method.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that the called Activity (started by `startActivityForResult()`) sets the result before finishing as follows:

```
Intent data = new Intent();
data.putExtra ("aValue", 42);
getActivity().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data);
finish();
```

In order to get the value in the calling activity, use

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case (PICK_CONTACT) :
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                int aValue = data.getIntExtra("aValue", -1);
            ....
    }
}
```

This example is based on an `int`, however, there are a lot of other value types can be passed. See Androids [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20double[]%29) documentation.

*p.s.*: let me add that it works in the same way with `void Intent.setData(Uri)` and `Uri Intent.getData()` instead of `putExtra(...)` and `getExtra(...)`