# Going from 3rd Activity to 1st Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have read on here that I have to use `startActivityForResult()` but I don't know how to exactly use it on my case, **Could someone help me integrate it?**

So in the `MainActivity`, the user logs in, from there it will start the `SecondActivity` and the user would be presented with two buttons, one for a third activity and the other is logging out, if the third activity is selected the user would be presented with a back button and a logout button, now the problem is that both buttons would just be going back to the second activity.

MainActivity.

```
public void login(View v){
        EditText uname_field = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.uname_field);
        EditText pword_field = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pword_field);

        username = uname_field.getText().toString();
        password = pword_field.getText().toString();
        if(username.equalsIgnoreCase("admin") && password.equalsIgnoreCase("admin")){
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Access Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
```

Second Activity

```
public void logout(View v) {
               finish();
    }

    public void viewProfile(View v){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ThirdActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Thirdactivity

```
public void logout(View v) {

        finish();

    }



    public void back(View v){

        finish();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't tested it in IDE, but you shoud get the idea :

Second Activity

```
static final int THIRD_ACTIVITY_REQUEST = 1;

    public void logout(View v) {
                   finish();
        }

        public void viewProfile(View v){
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, ThirdActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent,THIRD_ACTIVITY_REQUEST );
        }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == THIRD_ACTIVITY_REQUEST ) {
            if (data != null && data.hasExtra("userLoggedOut")) {
                finish();
            }
        }
    }
```

Third Activity :

```
   public void logout(View v) {

       Intent result = new Intent();
       result.putExtra("userLoggedOut", true);
       setResult(RESULT_OK, result);
       finish();

  }



        public void back(View v){

            finish();
        }
```

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

[Sending data back to the Main Activity in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920306/sending-data-back-to-the-main-activity-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

Just start FirstActivity.class from your ThirdActivity.class

```
public void logout(View v) {    
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, FirstActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("lastActivity", "third");
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void back(View v){

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, FirstActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("lastActivity", "third");
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

And add below code in FirstActivity.class for not going back to ThirdActivity.class from your FirstActivity.class while pressing back hardware button.

```
  public void onBackPressed() {
        if(getIntent().getExtras().getString("lastActivity").equals("third")){
           //from third activity
        } else{
           //from other activity, here you can exit or can do other things
        }
    }
```

To kill all activity except the first activity use

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FirstActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: and if user will press back in FirstActivity he will be again in Third activity (backstack)

Comment: that's a hardcode fix actually, how do we know who started FirstActivty ? the 3rd or maybe it's really started by user from home screen and then back button will be blocked unnecessarily ?

Comment: The developer must use logic according to his/her requirements. But I have edited my answer for getting acknowledgement for which activity was last time active.

Comment: it does not fix anything, the backstack of activities remains in memory, what if user will repeat First->Second->Third->First->Second->Third ..... OutOfMemoryException eventually will happen

Comment: I edited my answer. I hope the developer will understand and apply this according to his/her requirements. Thank You @MickeyTin