# Android data from database to listview

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I want to get data from another activity through `OnActivityResult`,put the data to sqllite and print to listview. What must I put to `OnActivityResult` method?

I really seen many examples but I don't understand them and now. Thanks for answers.

Comment: what type of data you want to get?

Comment: It's not short, but here's a tutorial on how to do it! Covers everything you need and will give you good practice
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Answer (score 0):

1. put the data to sqlite.
2. notifying to listview's adapter (corsur adapter)

that's all.

Answer (score 0):

Let assume you have two activity A , B and you want to pass data from B to A, where you start activity B from A. Now to get result from B you should start Activity B with the method startactivityforresult

```
static final int ACITIVITY_B_ID = 1;
startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, B.class), ACITIVITY_B_ID);
```

from activity A. Now from activity B you should set result like following

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
resultIntent.putExtra("key_of_str", "str_to_send");
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
finish();
```

Now onActivityResult of A should be called with that intent.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Check which request we're responding to
    if (requestCode == ACITIVITY_B_ID) {
        // Make sure the request was successful
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
           String data = intent.getStringExtra("key_of_str");
        }
    }
}
```

You may look into this answer
[Sending data back to the Main Activity in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920306/sending-data-back-to-the-main-activity-in-android)
and this one for details
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html