# Can't start second activity with "startActivityForResult"

Tags: android, xml, android-activity

Same as title: i already tried with "startActivity" but same result. When i press the fab button it shows the HomeActivity.
Hope you can help me.

Want to send the list of person from here

**Home Activity:**

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
public ArrayList result = new ArrayList();

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == 0 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data!=null){
        result = data.getParcelableArrayListExtra("list_modified");
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv);

    // use this setting to improve performance if you know that changes
    // in content do not change the layout size of the RecyclerView
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new ScaleInBottomAnimator());

    // use a linear layout manager
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    // specify an adapter (see also next example)
    mAdapter = new MyAdapter(createList(0));
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    fab.attachToRecyclerView(mRecyclerView);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, CreateNewPerson.class);
            i.putExtra("list", result);
            startActivityForResult(i, 0);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });


}
private List createList(int size) {

    for (int i=1; i <= size; i++) {
        Person p = new Person("Name"+ i, "Surname" + i, R.drawable.ic_action_account_box);
        result.add(p);
    }
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_home, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

to here, modify it and try to refresh my RecyclerView with new person
into it.

**SecondActivity:**

```
public class CreateNewPerson extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText e1;
EditText e2;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.new_person);
    Bundle extra= getIntent().getExtras();
    ArrayList<Person> list = (ArrayList) extra.getParcelableArrayList("list");
    e1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editName);
    e2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editSurname);
    Person p = new Person(e1.toString(), e2.toString(), R.drawable.ic_action_account_box);
    list.add(p);
    Intent output = new Intent();
    output.putExtra("list_modified", list);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, output);
    finish();

}

}
```

Comment: but you're finishing the 2nd activity as soon as starts (check finish( ); )

Comment: Yeah, you're right but i followd this http://stackoverflow.com/a/13362722
and it says that finish must be included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your second activity code with this

```
public class CreateNewPerson extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText e1;
EditText e2;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.new_person);
    Bundle extra= getIntent().getExtras();
    ArrayList<Person> list = (ArrayList) extra.getParcelableArrayList("list");
    e1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editName);
    e2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editSurname);
    Person p = new Person(e1.toString(), e2.toString(), R.drawable.ic_action_account_box);
    list.add(p);
    Intent output = new Intent();
    output.putExtra("list_modified", list);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, output);
}

}
```

Comment: Ok, thank you without "finish()" it works properly. But how can i come back to first activity with new list? Need to implement a button? Can't do it with back button?

Comment: Yes you need to implement a button. or your can add swipe to refresh in your first activity.