# How can I return an object from a created intent back to the method which called it?

Tags: android

I am calling a new Activity which displays a layout with a text box in a new activity for a text input.

```
  private void openDialogue()
        {   
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity_OpenDialogue.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

I wish to be able to access that text object from within my class which created the new activity, or pass that newly created object back to the calling class.  Note I do not want to simply access the string I wish to pass the entire EditText box object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending data back to the Main Activity in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920306/sending-data-back-to-the-main-activity-in-android)

Comment: Please do a normal google/SO search before posting questions. There are 100s of similar questions on SO. No need to post a new duplicate every time.

Comment: This answer is only sending a string back, I with the entire object to be passed back

Comment: @user2206836: this is my google search. Can you see anything https://www.google.co.in/search?q=passing+object+to+activity+android&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=-rKzVvOaBcHuugTVl5DwDQ

Answer (score 0):

You can start an activity for result like this [Activity for result](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html) also, you can send some extras to new activity and have it back.
Text object you think String class object?

Comment: Please don't answer for a question which has many many duplicates. Here is our discussion on meta http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315936/what-to-do-when-a-user-asks-for-acceptance

Answer (score 0):

With the Extra and Bundle methods from Intent, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233873/how-do-i-get-extra-data-from-intent-on-android) other question.

Comment: Please don't answer for a question which has many many duplicates. Here is our discussion on meta http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315936/what-to-do-when-a-user-asks-for-acceptance