# Going to previous activity with Intent Extras

Tags: android, android-intent

I have two activities. One has a a form with few `EditText`s. The values in these inputs should come from a master list and so, on focus of the EditText, I am taking the control to the another activity which uses 'android.support.v7.widget.SearchView`with a`ListView`

OnFocus of a EditText I invoke the SearchActivity with following code:

```
    ETVehicleRegnLoc.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener()  {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SearchActivity.class).putExtra("fieldName","RegnNum"));
            }
        }
    });
```

Once the value is selected I am sending the value back with the following code

```
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                                    long arg3) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(SearchActivity.this , VehicleActivity.class);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("SelectedVal", dataArray.get(arg2).toString());
                intent.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivity(intent);

//                Toast.makeText(SearchActivity.this, dataArray.get(arg2).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

This works fine. But because I am calling the `VehicleActivity` through `Intent`, its clearing the entire form of the values which are already entered.

But when I press the "back" button on the mobile, the values persist. But the purpose of going to the `SearchActivity` is not met :)

I think I have to simulate the back button press. how can i do it??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920306/sending-data-back-to-the-main-activity-in-android

Comment: In focus change call startActivityForResult. Then on back press from Search screen, set the bundle parameters in intent extras and call finish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SearchActivity.class).putExtra("fieldName","RegnNum"),2);
```

instead of

```
startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SearchActivity.class).putExtra("fieldName","RegnNum"));
```

And in onItemClickListener Do

```
Intent intent=new Intent();  
                intent.putExtra("MESSAGE",message);  
                setResult(2,intent);  
                finish();
```

And get the data in `OnActivityForResult` of your VehicleActivity

Comment: Is it possible to pass the whole extras dataset; not just named-key pairs?