# Get extra from child activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, parent-child

I got main activity CrimeListActivity (with fragment CrimeListFragment) calling CrimePagerActivity. In manifest I wrote:

```
   <activity android:name=".CrimePagerActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".CrimeListActivity"
        >
```

and in CrimePagerActivity i redefine "getParentActivityIntent" as :

```
   @Nullable
@Override
public Intent getParentActivityIntent() {

    boolean mSubt=getIntent().getBooleanExtra(EXTRA_CRIME_SUBTITLE,true);

    Intent intent=new Intent(this,CrimeListActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(CrimeListFragment.SAVED_SUBTITLE_VISIBLE,mSubt);
    return intent;
}
```

Now I want to "catch" this extra in List Activity, but I cann't find this extra neither in OnResume nor OnCreate of fragment.This question is unique cuz I am not talking starting activity for result, what I want is to override parent intent to send parent some data from child. Where can I find it?

```
package software.eligo.com.criminalintent;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

/**
 * Created by Bermud06 on 12.07.2016.
 */
public class CrimeListActivity extends SingleFragmentActivity {
    @Override
    protected Fragment createFragment() {
        return new CrimeListFragment();
    }
}




package software.eligo.com.criminalintent;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

/**
 * Created by Bermud06 on 12.07.2016.
 */
public abstract class SingleFragmentActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    protected abstract Fragment createFragment();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fragment);

        FragmentManager fm=getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment=fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer);

        if(fragment==null){
            fragment=createFragment();
            fm.beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragmentContainer,fragment)
                    .commit();
        }
    }
}


package software.eligo.com.criminalintent;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

/**
 * Created by mragl on 31.07.2016.
 */
public class CrimePagerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private List<Crime> mCrimes;

    private static final String EXTRA_CRIME_ID="com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent.crime_id";
    private static final String EXTRA_CRIME_SUBTITLE="com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent.visible_subtitle";

    public static Intent newIntent(Context packageContext, UUID crimeID,boolean subt){
        Intent intent=new Intent(packageContext,CrimePagerActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_CRIME_ID,crimeID);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_CRIME_SUBTITLE,subt);
        return intent;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Intent getParentActivityIntent() {

        boolean mSubt=getIntent().getBooleanExtra(EXTRA_CRIME_SUBTITLE,true);

        Intent intent=new Intent(this,CrimeListActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(CrimeListFragment.SAVED_SUBTITLE_VISIBLE,mSubt);
        return intent;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_crime_pager);

        UUID crimeID=(UUID)getIntent().getSerializableExtra(EXTRA_CRIME_ID);

        mCrimes=CrimeLab.get(this).getCrimes();

        mViewPager=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.activity_crime_pager_view_pager);







        FragmentManager fragmentManager=getSupportFragmentManager();
        mViewPager.setAdapter(new FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fragmentManager) {
            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                Crime crime=mCrimes.get(position);
                return CrimeFragment.newInstance(crime.getId());
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return mCrimes.size();
            }
        });

        for(int i=0;i<mCrimes.size();i++){
            if(mCrimes.get(i).getId().equals(crimeID)){
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
                break;
                }
        }

    }



}
```

Comment: Could you share the code of your CrimeListActivity.class

Comment: package software.eligo.com.criminalintent;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

/**
 * Created by Bermud06 on 12.07.2016.
 */
public class CrimeListActivity extends SingleFragmentActivity {
    @Override
    protected Fragment createFragment() {
        return new CrimeListFragment();
    }
}

Comment: Please edit your original question so that you can format the code.

Comment: Also, what are you trying to do exactly? What does the user do to navigate from `CrimeListActivity` to `CrimePagerActivity`? When the user is in `CrimePagerActivity` what action are you trying to respond to here? Are you trying to return data from `CrimePagerActivity` to `CrimeListActivity`?

Comment: Yes, in CrimeListActivity there is a boolean mSubtitleShow which determines the visibility of subtitle. I want to make parent remember its last value and restore it when returning from child PagerActivity

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending data back to the Main Activity in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920306/sending-data-back-to-the-main-activity-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This extra is passed as a bundle to the CrimeListActivity.class. In CrimeListActivity do this inside onCreate.

```
private boolean value;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    value = bundle.getBoolean(CrimeListFragment.SAVED_SUBTITLE_VISIBLE);

}
```

Comment: do you want me to redefine abstract class method? Coz in abstract class method evaluator doesn't show me what you say...

Comment: it worked bro!)
I used your solution (made "value " public to be able to access from fragment), then
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       Bundle bundle= getIntent().getExtras();
      if (bundle!=null){
         value=bundle.getBoolean(CrimeListFragment.SAVED_SUBTITLE_VISIBLE,false);
          if (savedInstanceState==null)
              savedInstanceState=new Bundle();
          savedInstanceState.putBoolean(CrimeListFragment.SAVED_SUBTITLE_VISIBLE,value);
      }
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); }

Comment: then in fragment I wrote

  @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        mSubtitleVisible=((CrimeListActivity)getActivity()).value;
    }

Comment: @IlqarRasulov This doesn't seem like a proper solution because it doesn't use the accepted method of communicating between an Activity and a Fragment.

Comment: @IlqarRasulov Now that I read your comment more closely, I understand more what you want to do. See my answer for a simple solution which requires only a few lines of code in `CrimeListActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

> in CrimeListActivity there is a boolean mSubtitleShow which determines the visibility of subtitle. I want to make parent remember its last value and restore it when returning from child PagerActivity

To save data in an Activity, you should overide [`onSaveInstanceState()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)). Then you restore the data in [`onRestoreInstanceState()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestoreInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)). You can do all of this in `CrimeListActivity`. `PagerActivity` should not be involved since this boolean value does not affect the behavior of this second activity.

Comment: don't wanna start activity for result... I want to override parent intent, it is not right solution I think

Comment: @IlqarRasulov Why do you want to override the parent intent? This doesn't do what you want to do.