# How to create 3 text fields and a button to show result on another activity in android studio?

Tags: java, android

I have activity_main and second_activity.
I have a button on activity_main that opens second_activity in a dialog.
How can I create three textEdit's with a button in second_activity and display the result when user submits on main_activity? 
This [Sending data back to the Main Activity in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920306/sending-data-back-to-the-main-activity-in-android) kind of solved my question.
It shows the first field's data on SecondActivity in all 3 textViews on MainActivity.

My current sample app code on SecondActivity

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
            EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById
            (R.id.etUsername);
            String stringToPassBack = editText.getText().toString();
            // put the string to pass back into an Intent and close 
            this activity
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra("@string/send", stringToPassBack);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
            finish();
        }
```

How do I add the other 2 fields; etPassword and etEmail

Comment: user inputs text in edit text in SecondActivity. but you want that to display in MainActivity?

Comment: Yes. I have tried a few tutorials on net but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920306/sending-data-back-to-the-main-activity-in-android.

1. Start the second activity with startActivityForResult.
2. Save the texts from the EditTexts into an intent, call setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent) and finish the activity.
3. Receive the result in your first activity in onActivityResult (the passed intent is holding the data).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending data back to the Main Activity in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920306/sending-data-back-to-the-main-activity-in-android)

Comment: Thanks. I looked at those links, and the information helped. I have three fields; username, password and email. (this is sample) The code on the links only helps with 1 field, I am struggling to get the other fields to work. It shows the first filed's data in all 3 textViews on MainActivity.

Answer (score 0):

In the `MainActivity` start `SecondActivity` with `startActivityForResult()` instead of `startActivity`:

```
startActivityForResult(intent, YOUR_REQUEST_CODE);
```

In second activity, when you want to close activity and come back to `MainActivity`, use this code:

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra("result",result);
setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
finish();
```

And again in `MainActivity` add a callback method `onActivityResult`:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == YOUR_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Your result is in data intent's extras
        }
    }
}
```