# Passing data from fragment to non hosting activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have tried finding a answer for my question but could not find anything, so I have **Activity A,Fragment A,Activity B**.

Activity A is hosting Fragment A, and i need to pass some data from Fragment A to Activity B how can i make that possible? i Know how to pass data to the hosting activity but i'm getting confused when trying to pass it to Activity B, can some one post a example with explanation how to make it possible?

Comment: Obviously you should treat this case as  normal activity - activity communication

Comment: Pass the data back to your hosting Activity then follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920306/sending-data-back-to-the-main-activity-in-android) to pass the data from that Activity to the next.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `getActivity()` or `getContext()` for getting activity context.

In your Fragment A, do like this.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("key", "value");
    // here you pass data
    getActivity().startActivity(intent);
```