# Clear data on the click of backpress of activity

Tags: android, android-preferences

I am getting stuck to clear the preference.
I created one method to use for all activities.

```
 public void clearMyPrefrences() {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preference.edit();
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();
    }
```

But In my `FirstActivity` there is some EditText on which I am opening new activity and searching some contents.On the click of `EditText` it will open `SecondActivity`. When I select some option from searchmenu and back to my `FirstActivity` it clears data before I typed. I am calling this method on the `onStop()`.I want to clear this data when I go back from the `FirstActivity`.So how should I do this??

How to clear data of preferences If I have two activites -
In FirstActivity -

there are some EditText.
On the click on the EditText -

SecondActivity opens.
In the SecondActivity I search some data and set the selected text in the EditText of FirstActivity.

But problem is when I search and set the Text of selected item It clears all the 
data of FirstActivity which I typed in my activity.

And When I call above method on the onStop() it is not working.

Please tell me if there is the solution for it.Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure I got what you're asking for...

Comment: i think you need to use startAcivityForResult() and onActivityForResult() in your first activity ! see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/40969871/6925888

Comment: then call it on onBackPressed() method

Comment: I called it onBackPressed() but its not working @Lucifer

Comment: Check my question.I updated@magicleon

Comment: Its sending data of SecondActivity to FirstActivity.It is not for clearing the preferences.@kdblue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `clearMyPreferences` in  `onDestroy()` instead of `onStop ()` to achieve your desired result.

Comment: I tried that,its not working.It clear data of FirstActivity when I come from SecondActivity to FirstActivity. I want to clear the data on the backpress of FirstActivity.@Sagar

Comment: How are u saving the data? You need to ensure you are not calling `finish()` when you start Second Activity.

Comment: I am saving data in shared preferences and I am not calling finish() when I start Second Activity.

Comment: Can you update your question with the code for saving? And starting Second Activity?