# StartActivityForResult not pausing Main Activity

Tags: java, android

I've created a Dialog as an activity, where the user checks one of three radio buttons and the result is returned to the main activity. I followed the [answer on this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40969871/3536292)

I thought that by creating this the MainAcitvity would pause and wait for a result from the child activity.

```
private void getFinalFinish() {

    Intent intent_openDialog = new Intent(this, DaAAmountToFinish.class);
    // Start the SecondActivity
    Bundle bundle_PassToDialog = new Bundle();

    bundle_PassToDialog.putInt("EXTRA_SCORE_TO_SUBTRACT", scoreToSubtractFrom);
    bundle_PassToDialog.putString("EXTRA_RADIO_BUTTON", rb_selected.getText().toString());
    bundle_PassToDialog.putString("EXTRA_THROWING", whosThrowing);        
    intent_openDialog.putExtras(bundle_PassToDialog);
    startActivityForResult(intent_openDialog, DIALOG_REQUEST_CODE);


}
```

This code is executed when wanted, I can see this as it is displayed whenever I hit the back button (My main activity continues to the point where it opens another activity that I only want to open after I get the result from activity as a dialog).

On activity result code...

```
 // This method is called when the dialog activity finishes
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Check that it is the SecondActivity with an OK result
    if (requestCode == DIALOG_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {


            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            // Get String data from Intent
            int darts_to_minus = extras.getInt("DARTS_TO_MINUS");
            boolean addTooScore = extras.getBoolean("ADD_TO_SCORE");
            int dartsToSubtractFromFinish = extras.getInt("DARTS_TO_SUBTRACT_FROM_FINISH");

            setMatchAVG(darts_to_minus, whosThrowing, addTooScore);


            if (newBestLeg) {

                if (whosThrowing.equalsIgnoreCase("Player 1")) {
                    tv_bestLeg.setText(getString(R.string.tv_BestLeg, String.valueOf(tempNumOfDartsThrownP1 + dartsToSubtractFromFinish))); //Subtract 2 off best leg only took 1 dart to finish
                } else {
                    tv_bestLegP2.setText(getString(R.string.tv_BestLeg, String.valueOf(tempNumOfDartsThrownP2 + dartsToSubtractFromFinish)));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Why is this?

Comment: please add the relevant code where you call getFinalFinish() so we can see what else is in the same scope.

Comment: it's just called from an if statement which is in a method with 200+ lines. Even then that method is called from another.

Comment: I have no onPause method in this Activity, would this matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My main activity continues to the point where it opens another activity that I only want to open after I get the result from activity as a dialog

This is "working as intended":

- once a method has started, it will continue until it is finished (if it doesn't take too long and so causes an ANR).
- The default thread for execution of `Activity` methods is the main thread. Specifically, if another `Activity` is started, its methods will be executed on the main thread as well.
- So the first method from the new `Activity` can only be executed once the method which started the new `Activity` has finished.
- it follows that you should move all the parts which have to wait for the result from the new `Activity` to another part of your app. You override `onActivityResult()` and trigger the execution of these parts based on the result.

Comment: Cheers will try implement this and report back