# Data sent through Intent to MainActivity is changing

Tags: java, android, android-room

I have an activity that passes updated information from my `EditBook` activity to my `MainActivity` via an Intent.

Button for `EditBook`:

```
FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String title = mTitle.getText().toString();
            String author =  mAuthor.getText().toString();
            String publisher = mPublisher.getText().toString();

            Intent replyIntent = new Intent();
            replyIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_ID, getIntent().getIntExtra(EXTRA_ID, -1));
            replyIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_TITLE, title);
            replyIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_AUTHOR, author);
            replyIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_PUBLISHER, publisher);
            replyIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_ISBN, getIntent().getStringExtra(BookView.EXTRA_ISBN));
            setResult(RESULT_OK, replyIntent);
            finish();

        }
    });
```

And my receiving end in `OnActivityResult`:

```
if (data.getIntExtra(EditBook.EXTRA_ID, -1) != -1) {

            Book book = new Book(data.getIntExtra(EditBook.EXTRA_ID, -1), data.getStringExtra(EditBook.EXTRA_TITLE),
                    data.getStringExtra(EditBook.EXTRA_AUTHOR), data.getStringExtra(EditBook.EXTRA_PUBLISHER),
                    "1", data.getStringExtra(EditBook.EXTRA_ISBN));

            try {
                asyncWait = mBookViewModel.update(book);
                spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.book_saved, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Intent intent = getIntent();
                finish();
                startActivity(intent);

            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

The `asyncWait` variable simply collects the result from AsyncTask so that my UI will update.

The book I am trying to edit has a title come back as "1984 (signetClassic)". In my `EditBook` activity, I change this to "1984" and click the save floating action button. When I step through the debugger, `title` does show the correct title, the `replyIntent` mMap shows the correct title, but when I inspect the data in the MainActivity, the title has reverted back to "1984 (signetClassic)". Any ideas why the Intent extras are changing when sent?

Let me know if there is any more information you need.

Comment: Pass Data Using Bundle

Comment: @SagarPoshiya the data still changes from "1984" in the `EditBook` activity to "1984 (signetClassic)" in the `MainActivity` with the bundle

Comment: @SagarPoshiya yes. And my onActivityResult method works fine with my other activities with the proper Intent extras

Comment: Go here to more complete response https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920306/sending-data-back-to-the-main-activity-in-android

Comment: Alright, apparently I just wasn't paying very good attention. When passing the data back, it passes through a third activity that reset the title back to what it was before I edited it. I was referencing the wrong key.