# How to add elements to a list from another class?

Tags: java, android

So i have my a list on my main activity that i want to be able to access in another class. The second class is supposed to add more records to the list based on the users input but i don't know how to access it. Can anybody help?

Contactos.java:
This is my main class and its also where the list is kept, i did a test run on it so that's why the constructor is filled with numbers. I want to be able to add to the list from another class.

```
public class Contactos extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button btnReciente;

    private ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnReciente = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Reciente);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);

        List<contactosLista> list1 = new ArrayList<contactosLista>();
        list1.add(new contactosLista("1","2","3","4","5","6"));

        ContactosAdapter adapter = new ContactosAdapter(this,list1);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

ContactosAdapter.java: This is where i inflate the list, i use it so i can use a .xml  file to better display the values in the list.

```
public class ContactosAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    private Context mContext;
    private List<contactosLista>mListaContactos;

    public ContactosAdapter(Context context, List<contactosLista> list)
    {
        mContext = context;
        mListaContactos = list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mListaContactos.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mListaContactos.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        contactosLista entrada = mListaContactos.get(position);

        if(convertView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contactos_row,null);
        }

        TextView Contact = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Contacto);
        Contact.setText(entrada.getmName() + " -- " + entrada.getmEmpresa());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

contactosLista.java: This the class that defines the elements that the list needs. i made a constructor that accommodates all the strings and made all the setters & getters

```
public class contactosLista
{
    private String mName;
    private String mEmpresa;
    private String mRazon;
    private String mDireccion;
    private String mEstatus;
    private String mPaquete;

    public contactosLista(String mName, String mEmpresa, String mRazon, String mDireccion, String mEstatus, String mPaquete)
    {
        this.mName = mName;
        this.mEmpresa = mEmpresa;
        this.mRazon = mRazon;
        this.mDireccion = mDireccion;
        this.mEstatus = mEstatus;
        this.mPaquete = mPaquete;
    }

    public String getmName() {
        return mName;
    }

    public void setmName(String mName) {
        this.mName = mName;
    }

    public String getmEmpresa() {
        return mEmpresa;
    }

    public void setmEmpresa(String mEmpresa) {
        this.mEmpresa = mEmpresa;
    }

    public String getmRazon() {
        return mRazon;
    }

    public void setmRazon(String mRazon) {
        this.mRazon = mRazon;
    }

    public String getmDireccion() {
        return mDireccion;
    }

    public void setmDireccion(String mDireccion) {
        this.mDireccion = mDireccion;
    }

    public String getmEstatus() {
        return mEstatus;
    }

    public void setmEstatus(String mEstatus) {
        this.mEstatus = mEstatus;
    }

    public String getmPaquete() {
        return mPaquete;
    }

    public void setmPaquete(String mPaquete) {
        this.mPaquete = mPaquete;
}
}
```

createContact.java: finally this is the class where i want to be able to access the list from Contactos.java, I have a layout file that has a bunch of Edit text so that i can record input from the user. When the user clicks on the button to save i want my void "GuardarCon" to save the input from the user to strings and then i want to use those strings as parameters for my list. This is where the problem arises, i don't know how to call the list. PLS help.

```
public class createContact extends AppCompatActivity
{
    EditText nombre;
    EditText empresa;
    EditText razon;
    EditText direccion;
    EditText estatus;
    EditText paquete;
    String snombre;
    String sempresa;
    String srazon;
    String sdireccion;
    String sestatus;
    String spaquete;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_contact);

        nombre = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nombreT);
        empresa = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.empresaT);
        razon = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.razonSocialT);
        direccion = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.direccionT);
        estatus = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EstatusT);
        paquete = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.paqueteT);
    }

    public void GuardarCon(View view)
    {
        snombre = nombre.getText().toString();
        sempresa = empresa.getText().toString();
        srazon = razon.getText().toString();
        sdireccion = direccion.getText().toString();
        sestatus = estatus.getText().toString();
        spaquete = paquete.getText().toString();

    }
```

Comment: WL sarl, your question bit confusing u want to show data of the list to createContact? please claify

Comment: I want to be able to add to the "list1" that is located in Contactos.java from createContact.java with the strings in the void "GuardarCon".

Comment: [Sending data back to the Main Activity in android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/920306)

Answer (score 0):

Create a singleton class and access and modify data as you want !

```
public class DataHolder{
    public static final DataHolder instance = new DataHolder();
private List<Your_Data_Type> data;

//Your methods goes here...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `startActivityForResult` method to start `createContact` from `Contactos` activity and after the addition process is done use `setResult` method to return the added item to the `Contactos` activity and handle adding the item to the list in `onActivityResult`.

take a look at this link for further info:

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result