# Android Intent Bundle passing returns always null

Tags: java, android, string, list, bundle

I am trying to pass text from a custom dialog to the home activity. The bundle always comes up as null instead of the value I'm trying to pass and I can't figure out why. I've tried looking at similar questions but I have yet to find a solution.

Dialog

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_ingredients_dialog);

    Button addButton = findViewById(R.id.addButton);
    addButton.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(AddIngredientsDialog.this,
                            android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, fruits);
                    editText.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
                    text = editText.getText().toString();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(AddIngredientsDialog.this, AddIngredientsActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("Text", text);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    dialog.dismiss();
            }

     });
}
```

Home Activity

```
 ingredientList = findViewById(R.id.listView);
 ArrayList<String> ingredients = new ArrayList<>();
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_ingredients);

    //bundle
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    text = extras.getString("Text");

    button = findViewById(R.id.add);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            ingredients.add(text);
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(AddIngredientsActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, ingredients);
            ingredientList.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your home activity, try using `getIntent().getStringExtra("Text")`, instead of `extras.getString("Text");`

```
//bundle
text = getIntent().getStringExtra("Text")
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem could be here

```
`text = editText.getText().toString();`
```

Make sure you've written something in EditText

Answer (score 0):

It is better using  startActivityForResult to start your dialog Activity. Check this answer [Sending data back to the Main Activity in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920306/sending-data-back-to-the-main-activity-in-android/947560#947560)