# how to update a fragment's recyclerview when another activty finishes?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have an activity that contains several fragments. in one of those fragments, there is a `RecyclerView`.
there is a second activity that starts from the `RecyclerViewAdapter`.

in the second activity, the user can change the recyclerview data and when the second activity finishes the recyclerview should reload to show those changes.

the problem is I cannot reload the whole fragment and I can't access the recyclerview from the first activity because it's in a fragment. I tried to use `getView()` to get the instance of fragment view to reload the recyclerview but the app crashed because of `null object reference`.

what is the best way to do this?

Comment: Typically, what you want to do is to have the RecyclerView `observe` the data source that is updated by the second Activity. There are many ways to do this but i'd recommend using `LiveData`. Tak e alook at https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-training-livedata-viewmodel?hl=en&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fcodelabs.developers.google.com%2F#0

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to `reload` your `fragment` instead while navigation to `secondActivity` from your `RecyclerViewAdapter` you should use `startActivityForResult()` and then use `setResult` to send your data back to your `FirstActivity`.

For understanding how to use `onActivityResult` in `Activity` and `Fragments` you can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147884/onactivityresult-is-not-being-called-in-fragment) link and to understand how to use `setData` in `activity` you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/947560/12768366) link.

After that you can retrieve your updated data using `OnActivityResult` and in that you can reload your `recyclerView`.

Comment: the problem is not retrieving data, is reloading the ```recyclerview```. I'm not sure if I'm missing something here but I tried most solution on how to do ```reload``` a ````recyclerview``` from an ```activity``` but none of them worked

Comment: Why do you need to reload that recyclerView from the activity ? you can simple reload that from your fragment itself.